# PHP files on Apache web server is not echoing JSON output

Tags: php, mysql, apache

I am trying to create a REST API to gather/send some data to a MySQL database I have running on a RHEL 7 Server. I have made a series if php files that I uploaded into my apache document root that for now simply connects to the DB and then lists all the entries from every table. When I run the PHP files from the server in command line, I get the appropriate JSON output echoed out to the terminal.

However, when I visit my server from a remote web browser, going to the PHP files results in a blank page every time. I have ensured that PHP is configured correctly is apache's httpd.conf file so I am very lost as to what my next steps should be.

Edit: Here is one of my PHP files:

```
<?php


$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","dbname");


if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM dbname.Table;";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
        $resultArray = array();
        $tempArray = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_object())
        {
                $tempArray = $row;
            array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
        }

        echo json_encode($resultArray);
}


mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: Fancy pasting some of the aforementioned php code into your question?

Comment: First step _always_ is to take a look into your http servers error log file. Until  you add the information in that file no further comment or answer makes any sense.

Comment: Sure @Dan. I'll edit it now

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: Have you looked in the error logs?